# Remove Right side bar from continue shopping page

Tags: magento, sidebar

User click on "place order" and comes to success order page. Now my question is , If i want to remove right side bar from this page,then which procedure I have to follow.

Thank You

Comment: can you elaborate. as this question is of no sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\checkout.xml , replace

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

with ...

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

you actually saying in success page of checkout display page as 1 column